Lagrange Multipliers: How does one prove the existence of a global minimum?
Let $a > 0$. Using Lagrange Multipliers, I wish to solve the problem:
\begin{align}
& \text{find the global minimum of: } f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^{-1} \\
& \text{subject to } g(x) =  \prod_{i=1}^{n} x_i - a = 0,  \\
& \qquad \qquad \text{ } \text{ } x_1, x_2, ..., x_n > 0. 
\end{align}
Using the Lagrange Multiplier Theorem (First Order Necessary Conditions), if $x^{*}$ is a local minimum of $f$ on $M = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \backslash \{0\}: g(x) = 0\}$, then there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla f(x^{*}) + \lambda \nabla g(x^{*}) = 0.$ From this, I was able to deduce that $x^{*} = (a^{1/n}, ..., a^{1/n}),$ with $\lambda = 1/(a^{1 + 1/n}).$ Since each component of $x^{*}$ is positive, $x^{*}$ is a feasible point.
All points of $M$ are regular points, that is, points for which $\nabla g(x) \neq 0$. The Lagrangian matrix of $f$ at $x^{*}$ is given by $L(x^{*}) = a^{-3/n}(I_n + J_n)$, where $J_n$ is the matrix of all ones. Clearly, $L(x^{*})$ is positive definite on the tangent space $T_{x^{*}}M$, so, by the Second Order Sufficient Conditions, $x^{*}$ is a strict local minimum of $f$ subject to the constraints.
I am confused now as to how to show $x^{*}$ is a global minimum of $f$ on $M$. Indeed, $M$ is not compact, though it is closed, so the EVT does not immediately apply.

An indirect way to verify this is a global minimum is to use AM-GM inequality. $\sum x_i^{-1}\geq n \big(\prod x_i)^{-1/n}=n a^{-1/n}$. The solution you found with Lagrange multipliers is exactly the one that satisfies the equality. Of course, this kind of defeats the purpose of looking at Lagrange multipliers for this particular problem in the first place :)

I think (but am not entirely sure) that if you let $x_i = \exp(y_i)$ and take the logarithm of your equality constraint, then your minimization problem becomes a proper convex minimization problem. And for convex optimization problems a local extremum is a global extremum.

This is a Generalized Geometric Programming problem (hence, can be reformulated as a convex optimization problem), so all stationary points are global optima.
Presuming numerical values have been set for n and a, this can be written in CVX (see CVX Users' Guide Geometric Programming chapter) as:
cvx_begin gp
variable x(n)
minimize(sum(inv_pos(x)))
subject to
prod(x) == a
cvx_end

